# How can I attach a file to the email in Jenkins?

Tags: linux, email, jenkins, attachment

I have a problem now with Jenkins Email. I tried to attach a file like demo.html in the $WORKSPACE. But it didn't work. I just received an email with build.log attached. Could someone figure out what's the problem?

I am now doubting that the email is processing in Jenkins master, and my job is working in slave. Is that the reason?

Here is Attachments filed in Editable Email Notification. I filled it with "*.html"

============

Attachments      *.html

============

I also tried ./*.html in Attachments field, but with no luck.

A part of build log:

```
completed with result SUCCESS

Checking if email needs to be generated

Email was triggered for: Success

Sending email for trigger: Success

NOT overriding default server settings, using Mailer to create session

messageContentType = text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Request made to attach build log

Adding recipients from recipient list

Adding developers

Successfully created MimeMessage

Sending email to: test999922@hotmail.com

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Which email plugin are you using?

Comment: sorry, I am not sure. The Jenkins server have already been set up before I get involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. 
The html is in the salve's workspace not in master's workspace. So jenkins cannot find it.
When I restrict it run on slave, the problem is resolved.